# Assigning array with literal string index to an array with numeric index

Tags: php, arrays

How to assign an array with literal string index to an array with numeric index in PHP?

Both have the same length, for example

Literal: `array(HELL0=>somevalue1,BYE=>somevalue2)`

Numeric index: `array(1=>somevalue1,2=>somevalue2)` [Expected result in second array]

Both have same length / count of values 2.

Comment: Do you mean `array(0=>"somevalue1",1=>"somevalue2")` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_values](http://www.php.net/array_values). The indexing will start with 0 though.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [array_values](http://array_values)?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space)*.

I actually resolved it as:

```
new_array=array_keys($arrayold)
```

My question was quoted wrongly.